# Bootstrap modal popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code to display a bootstrap modal popup in a webforms application with a master page. This works fine on a small one-page test site. But when I move it to my actual site, somehow the popup doesn't show up. There are no javascript errors for me to debug. I have moved around, the javascript code to master page's head and also the modal popup div to the master page's body. Still the popup doesn't show!

aspx page:

```html
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <style>
    .vertical-alignment-helper {
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .vertical-align-center {
      /* To center vertically */
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() {
      $("#btnShowPopup").click();
    }

    function btnRedirect_Click() {
      window.location.replace("Redirected.aspx?
        FirstName = John & LastName = Velu ");
      }
  </script>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Display Popup" OnClick="OnClick" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" data- keyboard="false">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
      <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content ">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: white">
              Test</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Testing..." />
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRedirect" OnClick="Javascript:btnRedirect_Click();">
                        Redirect</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">
                        Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnShowPopup" class="btn 
      btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">       
     </button>

</asp:Content>
```

Code-behind

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.Redirect("Redirected.aspx");
 }

 protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", 
   "ShowPopup();", true);            
   return;
 }
```

Comment: When you click on `#btnShowPopup` (I know its hidden, for test, display it) is the popup shows up? Another question, when you click on `<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Display Popup" OnClick="OnClick" />` the page is refreshing?

Comment: make sure that you have the `bootstrap.min.js` in your file and double check the button id duplicate `#btnShowPopup`.

Comment: Hi Mosh, when I made #btnShowPopup visible and clicked it, it displays the modal popup in my test site but not in my actual site. Clicking on <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Display Popup" OnClick="OnClick" /> do refresh the page. Thanks

Comment: I have found out the issue. In the actual site, bootstrap.min.js was not included in the loaded set of files, although it was part of the solution :(